# Office 365 SharePoint Approval Workflow Limits

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow

I have an approval workflow setup in Office 365 SharePoint and the first branch sets up a 1 week delay while the other side of the branch is the "Start and wait for an approval". At the end of the delay, a conditional checks the value of a column to see if the approval is still pending, if it is it causes a reminder email to be sent and then closes the workflow. This delay branch causes the workflows to stay open for at least a week - ie they are staying in the running state.

Does this cause a problem for the quotas on SharePoint? Is there a way to cancel the delay if the workflow has been approved/rejected? Is there another way to do the reminder branch without a delay?

Comment: are you using SP Designer workflow or Flow?

Comment: @MarekSarad - I'm using Flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Limits and configuration in Microsoft Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/limits-and-config#run-duration-and-retention), there is a 30 day limit to the duration of any Flow.  If your Flow exceeds this, it will time-out.  If your Flow is expected to run for around one week only, you should be safe.